# Why the nature of things is such as it is?

Tags: philosophy, reality

Namaste. My question is

*Why the nature of things is such as it is?*

I think that the question cannot be answered, because it points outside the grasp of our mind, but I am interested in possible deep evidences pro or contra.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you say the nature of things i am assuming you mean things being:

**1.Impermanent (anicca)**

**2.Suffering/Dissatisfaction/Dis-Ease (dukkha)**

**3.Non Self (annatta)**

***1.Why is the nature of things impermanent?***

Because conditioned phenomenon is constantly in a state of flux.Why?Because something causes this to happen than this causes that to happen then that causes that to happen then...and so forth.

***2.Why is the nature of things suffering/dissatisfaction/Dis-Ease?***

Because the conditioned phenomenon keeps changing.(impermanence).And we keep grasping at it.What happens when you try to hold on to something that keeps moving and your adamant about staying put.You hurt yourself.You stress yourself.Let go.

***3.Why is the nature of thing Annatta?***

I can not answer this.**It just IS**.

Both Samsara and Nibbanna are devoid of an Ego.Both conditioned and the unconditioned have no permanent self/Ego.

Answer (score 3):

This is a broad question, perhaps a whole category of questions.

- Is the world like it is because it was created that way (by a creator God) for some reason?

  No, Buddhism doesn't accept/teach about a '[creator deity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_in_Buddhism)'.
- What do we know about the creation of the world?

  Not much: it has "[no discernible beginning](http://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=12631)".
- What ought we to care about the creation of the world?

  The Buddha said that instead of talking about such things, his intention was to teach about suffering and the end of suffering.
- What is the nature of things?

  The nature of things includes the 'three marks of existence', the laws of 'karma' and 'dependent origination', etc. etc.

Perhaps some interesting questions include:

- Why do we perceive the nature of things to be as we perceive it?

  Answers to that question include the theory of 'skandhas' and of 'identity view'.
- Can we change the nature of things?

  Well, good actions and evil actions, skillful and unskillful actions, have an effect.
- Can we change our perception of the nature of things?

  Supposedly yes: doings so is pretty well the purpose of Buddhism.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**: Because that's the way it is, and it doesn't matter.  Please read [The Parable of the Poisoned Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Poisoned_Arrow).

**Long Answer**:

There is no satisfying answer to this question because we're only asking because things happen to be this way.  If they were another way, we'd ask why things were THAT way.

It may be better to ask instead why you are asking that question.  Why not just accept that this is reality and that's that?  The very question you ask implies an attempt to give human existence cosmological importance. If so, what does this say about the attachment to your belief in your importance?  In short, is the question itself a symptom of an anthrocentric bias or agenda?

Now let's bring this back to Buddhism.

If you want to know why things are the way they are, then there is a Buddhist parable which is THE BEST Buddhist teaching I've seen on this and other metaphysical questions. It's called [The Parable of the Poisoned Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Poisoned_Arrow).  If you haven't read it, I recommend you do.  It teaches that only thing that matters is relieving your suffering, so stop the pointless speculation.

If you spend your time worrying about these things, then not only will you be distracted from the only thing that matters (relieving your suffering), but you may increase your suffering by agonizing about something you can't change.  Yes, nothing is more conducive to suffering than worrying about what's out of your control.

Which brings us to suffering. Buddhism has its [3 Marks of Existence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence). I'd interpret that as the 3 Marks of Experience. After all, suffering does not exist in the universe -- rocks, planets, and hydrogen atoms don't suffer, or at least I don't think they do.  Suffering is our REACTION to things, a reaction we can change, and this is where Buddhism is (and should always be)  situated.

Trying to elevate suffering into some kind of cosmological principle misses the point, and makes relieving suffering harder, by dramatizing it. Realizing the true role of suffering can put it into perspective and this itself is a big step towards relieving it.

Comment: The parable of the poisoned arrow always seemed like a cop-out to me. The historical Buddha seems happy to speak of many other esoteric, metaphysical things not directly related to the goal eliminating/escaping suffering, so his silence on the “unanswerable questions” on that basis seems suspect to my deluded, ego-attached mind.

Comment: @BrentCaldwell which is as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

We don't see the nature of things since:

- our mind is not focused enough
- our mind is clouded by perception

So my developing insight leading to the cessation of perception and developing concentration you can see things as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Before we come here, it is not easy  to see that a) 
to get to b) means... I will suffer this and that. Before we come, all we 
know is we wish to get from a) to b). For beings who are willing to see
 past the illusion, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To give you personally fulfilment and happiness in everything you do. Could there be any other meaning for you? Some questions are merry-go-rounds, all take part and everyone goes round and round for fun. This one isn't like that. Or if it is, it is a roundabout for one.